# How to GroupBy on two keys with linq-es2015?

Tags: javascript, angular, linq

Short question: How to groupby on two keys by using linq-es2015 in an Angular app?

One key works well, but I got no idea how to add another key.

```
var results = asEnumerable(fieldtoregion)
      .GroupBy(x => x.regionId, x => x, (key, b) => {
        return { regionId: key, fields: asEnumerable(b).ToArray() }
      }).ToArray();
```

The second key name: isCollection.
I tried:

1. x => { r: x.regionId, c: x.isCollection }
2. x => ({ r: x.regionId, c: x.isCollection })
3. x => ("$x.regionId $x.isCollection")

Any help would be greatful!!

Here is the TypeScript class to test:

```
export class FieldViewModel {
  id!: number;
  postId!: number;
  pageId!: number;
  regionId?: string | undefined;
  translationId!: number;
  clrType?: string | undefined;
  fieldId?: string | undefined;
  isCollection!: boolean;
}
```

Comment: do you have some data to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use only the third and fourth parameter for grouping. The grouping string is made of the two properties with a space.

```
var results = asEnumerable(fieldtoregion)
        .GroupBy(
            null,
            null,
            (key, b) => ({ regionId: key, fields: asEnumerable(b).ToArray() }),
            "$.regionId + ' ' + $.isCollection"
        )
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: I tried but GroupBy have 3 parameters only. https://github.com/ENikS/LINQ/wiki/groupby

Comment: i as thinking in therms of linq.js of http://neue.cc/reference.htm, where `groupBy` has 4 parameters. anyway, you need to use an indicator of a combined key for grouping somwhere.